# Is it possible to pass command-line arguments to an executable via an associated file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, command-line

I have a program that passes command-line arguments to an associated file (i.e. associated file extension) of an executable. The executable never receives the arguments. However, if I start the executable directly and pass it both the path to the associated file  and the arguments, then it receives both the file path and the arguments.

- Operating System: Windows XP
- Programming Language: C#

I am starting the associated file using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filepath, arguments)
```

Thanks in advance for all assistance.

-EDIT

Basically, I have a programming language interpreter that needs to receive command-line arguments passed to it by a C# program.

If I start a code file using the C# program, the interpreter will start, but not receive the command-line arguments that were passed to the code file by the C# program.

So there are a total of three files:

1. the interpreter
2. the code file
3. the program trying to start the code file as though it were a program

Also, starting the interpreter directly is not an option, because it is not located at the same file path on every computer.

I hope this is clearer, but I cannot post the source code do to legal restrictions.

Comment: Please could you post a bit of source, as I'm not quite 'getting' what you're after.

Comment: It seems to me he's doing Process.Start("file.xls", "arg1 arg2");

Comment: And what works is Process.Start("excel.exe", "file.xls arg1 arg2");

Comment: (updated to include example of it working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *try* <s>(untested)</s> changing the file association (on the advanced pane) to include %2 %3 etc in the arguments (normally it just includes %1) - however, this involves changes at the client, and (more importantly) the entire idea of passing arguments to a *document* presumes that you have the same viewer (i.e. that the arguments are sensible).

IMO, a better option is to explicitly launch the exe, passing the doc (and the other others) as arguments.

Example:

receiver exe (just shows the command arguments received):

```
static class Program {
    [System.STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string.Join("|", args));
    }
}
```

Then: created a "foo.flibble" file, right-click/open and associate with my receiver; went into file associations, "flibble", advanced, "open", edit, and added %2 %3 %4

Then in a separate exe:

```
Process.Start(@"c:\foo.flibble", "test of args");
```

Which shows:

```
c:\foo.flibble|test|of|args
```

So this **has** now passed the extra arguments to the exe via the document. But a lot of client configuration!